# jQuery: Run event except a td contains a textarea

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery. I want to create event if someone clicks a tr in a special table. But the event should not run if a td of an tr contains an textarea.
Something like this:

```
#table tbody tr td:not(td textarea)
```

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Is this such a special condition that you cant just put a classname on the non-textarea having td's? All this `has()` stuff doesn't seem so performant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [jQuery has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
jQuery('#table tbody tr td:not(:has(textarea))')
```

Comment: I'm glad that i could help sir,

Comment: Note that using .filter instead of pseudo selector :not:has is about twice more performant (http://jsperf.com/not-has-vs-filter)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the jQuery [**has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/) selector for this.

> has() - Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant
>   that matches the selector or DOM element.